# Jquery how send hidden value to my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use ASP.NET MVC and Jquery. I have icon, when I click on it shows dialog box.

Reports.cshtml:

```
<a class="dialog-opener" href="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="reportID" value="@view.ReportCode"/>
    <i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i>
</a>
```

in this dialog box I have form it is partial view
SubscriptionForm.cshtml:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic model dialog">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubscriptionForm", "Subscription", FormMethod.Get)) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        ...
</div>
```

_LayoutForAll.chhtml:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        title:"Formularz subskrypcji",
        show: {
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    $('.dialog-opener').click(function () {
        var reportId = $("[type=hidden]").val();
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        alert(reportId);
    });
 });
```

I need send reportId from Reports.cshtml and date from form SubscriptionForm to my controller, I don't now how do this.

Comment: Use `<a class="dialog-opener" href="#" data-id="@view.ReportCode">` and remove the hidden input. Then add a hidden input to the form - `<input type="hidden" name="reportID" id="reportID" />` and use `$('.dialog-opener').click(function () { $('#reportID').val($(this).data('id'); $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");});`

Answer (score 0):

give ID to your hidden filed and get value using jquery

```
    <a class="dialog-opener" href="#">

                        <input type="hidden" id="myhiddenfield" name="reportID" value="@view.ReportCode"/>

                        <i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i>
                    </a>
```

below code use for get value from hidden field.

```
  $('.dialog-opener')
    .click(function () {
        var reportId = $("#myhiddenfield").val();
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        alert(reportId);
    });
```

try above code . its working fine.

Comment: when I use     <input type="hidden" class="myhiddenfield" name="reportID" value="@view.ReportCode"/>

in script i have only first value